# Get User Comments from a Prompt Box also on Cancellation

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a HTML application (with Javascript, CSS). It is an user-interaction based application. I have a requirement where the user gets a prompt box with option to enter his/ her comments and to either accept (OK) or reject (Cancel) the action. When the user accepts (OK) i can read the user-comments. However, **I also want capture the user comments when the Cancel button is pressed**. 
Most of the examples which I saw (either using custom box or window.prompt) only read the inputs on OK but nothing on cancel. Also as per window.prompt definition it does not read the comments box on cancellation. How can this be achieved?

```
if (alertInfo.indexOf(checkString) > -1){//check if a string is present in the message
    var showPrompt = window.prompt("Please enter your remarks", "");
    if(showPrompt != null){ 
       userAccepted(showPrompt);
    }
    else{
       sendRejection();// This is where I also need to read the user comments
    }
 }
 else{
    //reload the page
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I know window.prompt cannot be used to read the inputs on "Cancel". However, I also do not know what to use which will also read the user inputs on cancellation.

Comment: `function userAccepted(showPrompt);` – that's a syntax error, you probably meant `userAccepted(showPrompt);`. Otherwise you should be fine.

Comment: yes that was my typo....thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a floating div, the user was directed to a new page where he / she could enter the inputs and either accept or reject the action. The advantage of having a separate page is that the user does not have to zoom-in / out the page to properly view the contents.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to misuse the feature. Cancel means *cancel*, not "OK but do something else". That's why you can't do this.

You'll have to find another way, such as rendering your own `<form>` to obtain the comments.

Comment: Yes, I know window.prompt cannot be used to read the inputs on "Cancel". However, I also do not know what to use which will also read the user inputs on cancellation. I cannot use a <form> as the requirement is to show the user a pop-up box.

Comment: "Popups" do not rule out forms. How about a form in a floating div? jQuery dialog? Search - there are hundreds of possibilities. If your requirement is strictly for a native UI modal pop-up (as your question suggests), then refer to my answer: you can't.

Comment: _How about a form in a floating div? jQuery dialog?_ - thanks for the hint. I have got some references on how to do this....trying to implement....will soon come with the results.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lightness Races in Orbit said, you simply can't do it with the windows prompt. You have to make a floating div and make it visible instead of the windows prompt.

You can have radio buttons that requires the user to accept or decline, a text box to enter comments and a single OK button to close the dialog ("basically hiding the DIV").